# C++ Operator, How does this code snippet work and how?

Tags: c++, operators

I came across this code snippet while learning about how operators and such work in C++ and for the life of me I don't understand it. I know that it outputs "412". But I don't understand how it does so. A simple clean explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
int main()
{
int a[5] = { 1 }, b[] = { 4, 1, 2, 0, 3 };
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{ 
    if (!(a[i] = b[i])) break; // note: = not ==
    cout << a[i];
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. You need to differentiate between syntax and semantics.

Comment: My bad, sorted formatting.

Comment: You could step through the code in a debugger and inspect the values of variables after each statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` operator assigns the value on the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side and returns the value. The `!` operator returns true if the argument is `0` and returns false otherwise.

Putting these together, we can say that one iteration of the loop does the following:

1. Assigns `b[i]` to `a[i]`
2. Breaks if `a[i]` (which is now equal to `b[i]`) is zero
3. Prints `a[i]` (which again is now equal to `b[i]`)

Thus, the code as a whole will print elements of `b` until it reaches the first 0. This results in printing '412'.